# Combining Google Maps coordinates with an existing shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, google-maps, coordinates

I would like to add GPS coordinates from Google Maps (see image below) as point data in QGIS and combine it with an existing shapefile [dvg1_EPSG25832_Shape.zip] https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/vkg/dvg/dvg1/.
[image]

Unfortunately the dots don't fit to the shapefile (see image below).
[image]

I think the problem is due to different Coordinate Reference Systems, but I don't know how solve it.

Comment: Maybe the problem arises when importing the text data. Did you make sure to specify the CRS of the coordinates? I guess they are WGS84 = EPSG:4326

Comment: GPS is unlikely to use Web Mercator, so tangling with coordinates in Google Maps may distract you from your task. Please [Edit] the question to specify the CRS generated by the GPS (ought to be WGS84) and the CRS of the shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

The X and Y of your GPS table are in Geographical Coordinates: select the coordinate system for your GPS table EPSG:4258 (ETRS89), that should plot them in Germany. The shapefiles should then plot together with your points.